# Break While loop in NodeJS when Async function is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have the following node js script:

```
const rp = require('request-promise')
let result = ''
let asyncdone = false
async function m() {
    return await rp.get('http://google.com')
}

m().then((html) => {
    result = html
    asyncdone = true
}).catch((e) => console.log(e))

while (!(asyncdone)) {
    console.log('processing...')
}
console.log(result)
```

When ran, the loop is infinite.
*'processing...'* keeps printing even though the async function should have set the *asyncdone boolean* as true, and thus break the loop, then log the *result*.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Why are you using a while loop when you already an use promises? That's the whole point of async/await, that you can wait for an async task to finish, and not have to wait like this...

Comment: OMG! This is the worst idea ever! The `while` loop is totally *blocking*. It will loop infintely, never giving control back to the event loop to run your asynchronous code. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I'll change the code to the following one if you only want to log `processing...` once.

```
var statuslogged = false;
while (true) {
  if (!statuslogged) {
    console.log('processing...');
    statuslogged = true;
  }
  if (asyncdone) {
    console.log(result)
  }
}
```

Comment: it does not break out of the _while (!(asyncdone)) {.......}_ loop.
the result does not get logged.
the aim is for _processing..._ to be repeatedly printed until the result is available.

Comment: @nas96 my fault sir, I misunderstood your question I updated the code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

`while` is actually doing the right thing.

Since it's checking the condition continuously without any delay and getting true everytime, it's printing the info on console, if it does Million checks in a second and the conditions are met, the console will print the string.

So, we need to add a timeout/interval (called pollInterval) so that it checks only after desired time.

I have a different solution for your problem. You want to show progress/a filler text while the promise is going on.

```
const rp = require('request-promise')

// The base wrapper to stop polluting the environment
async function getHTML(url) {

    // A sample filler function
    function doSomethingElse() {
        console.log(`Processing`);
    }

    // a filler function to use it later inside
    function ensureData({
        fillerFn,
        pollInterval = 500
    }) {
        let result;

        // grab the data and set it to result async
        rp.get(url)
            .then((html) => {
                result = html
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e))

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // a self-executing function
            (function waitForFoo() {
                // if there is result, resolve it and break free
                if (result) return resolve(result);

                // otherwise run the filler function
                fillerFn()

                // execute itself again after the provided time
                setTimeout(waitForFoo, pollInterval);
            })();
        });
    }

    // return or run it
    ensureData({
            fillerFn: doSomethingElse,
            pollInterval: 500
        })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
}

getHTML('http://httpbin.org/ip');
```

Comment: very well explained. thanks a lot sir!